# updateOne, $setOnInsert operation is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Before performing the `updateOne` and `setOnInsert` operation,

```sh
> db.blog.posts.findOne()

< { 
   _id: ObjectId("6199f4a6e441680652333cbc"),
   content: '...',
   comments: [ 
      { comment: 'good post', author: 'John', votes: 0 }
     ] 
   }
```

After performing the `updateOne` and `setOnInsert` operation,

```sh
> db.blog.posts.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("6199f4a6e441680652333cbc")}, {"$setOnInsert" : {"createAt" : new Date()}}, {"upsert" : true})

< { 
   acknowledged: true,
   insertedId: null,
   matchedCount: 1,
   modifiedCount: 0,
   upsertedCount: 0 
  }
```

Print the result.

```sh
> db.blog.posts.findOne()

< { 
   _id: ObjectId("6199f4a6e441680652333cbc"),
   content: '...',
   comments: [ 
      { comment: 'good post', author: 'John', votes: 0 }
     ] 
   }
```

It never works... I read many articles but I couldn't find reasons why not working.
Please help me teachers.....

Comment: What do you mean by never works / not working? Your document already exists and it is as expected the the document is not updated since you only specified the `$setOnInsert` behaviour

Comment: @ray Oooh I got it!!! Thank you ray teacher!!!! Have a nice day!!!